# Power Apps (SQL Server connector) - Overflow of a Numeric column when I charge data inside of a Gallery

Tags: sql-server, powerapps, connector

I've been having problems when I charge data from a SQL Server table inside a Gallery, the issue is that the Gallery has problems to show one of the columns. It's showing a different value.

I have a SQL Server like this:

LoadingFiles (idFile [int],  name varchar[4] ..... CDRV numeric (18,0)).

So I've transfered the data from "LoadingFiles" into a Collection named "colLoadFiles", but when I put the collection in the Gallery's Datasource the CDRV value which was correct in the collection is different from the showed value in the gallery.

I think it could be a problem related to Overflow because the number is too big, but I don´t know how to solve it.

I mean, If in in the datatable has a CDRV value like this: 4235423575762727000 then in "colLoadFiles" has the same value "4235423575762727000" but when I use "ThisItem.CDRV" the gallery shows the altered/corrupted value  like this "423542357576272000" (the last 7 in the ending part ...72-7-000 has disappeared).

Comment: How many digits are in `4235423575762727000`? How many digits are allowed in `numeric(18,0)`?

Comment: Last time I've checked there are 18 digits and ThisItem.CDRV has 18 digits also, so it's showing a corrupted value. Also I've tried with Int(Text(ThisItem.CDRV)) or Value(Text(ThisItem.CDRV))  but It results in other corrupted value.

Comment: There are nineteen digits in `4235423575762727000` - is that a real example of incoming data?

Comment: It's a number that I've made up, the real case is: this.CDRV ---> 384370136270936600 but In my data I have 384370136270936640

Comment: The error indicates that some of the data you're attempting to load has 19 or more digits. It could only be a single value in a single row. It could even be due to something like a missing delimiter in the source file. There's not much you can do here except maybe load the file into a staging table with a larger column, say using the longest possible `numeric(38,0)`, and then search for values that would overflow `numeric(18,0)` fix the source file and try to import again.

Comment: So, there is no type in Power Apps that could support bigger Number without losing precision? I've read that Power App numeric limits are defined by Javascript, but in JavaScript we have BigInt to get a bigger number without losing precision, something that in the case of Power Apps I understand is not possible. Thanks for your answer!